# custom tooltip appear out of the page window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I designed a tool tip using the following code.

```
function showToolTip(posX, posY, elem){
    if($(elem).find('.item-name').css('overflow') == "hidden"){
        $newDiv = $('<div></div>');
        $newDiv.css("display", "none");
        $newDiv.addClass('tooltip');
        $newDiv.append($(elem).attr('title'));
        $newDiv.appendTo("body");
        $newDiv.fadeIn().css(({ left:  posX, top: posY }));
    }
    if($(elem).hasClass('bill-item')){
        $newDiv = $('<div></div>');
        $newDiv.css("display", "none");
        $newDiv.addClass('tooltip');
        $newDiv.append($(elem).find('.bill-item-name-left').html());
        $newDiv.appendTo("body");
        $newDiv.fadeIn().css(({ left:  posX, top: posY }));
    }
}

function hideToolTip(){
    $('.tooltip').fadeOut();
}
```

I use the position x nd y of a clicked element and display a div element for a certain time. The thing is, when the element is near the right end of the page, it appears allright. But the tool tip div is out of the page window and the horizontal scroll bar appear. I tried changing the porition to right when the div is created but then the div appears in the left most of the page. How can I make the div appear in the right of the mouse click if the mouse is near the page end.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are plenty of jQuery plugins for custom tooltips I'm sure most of them already know to handle those cases.

Comment: Yeah you are correct! bt in my case, my team lead wants me to develop a new one! :(

Comment: can you tell how you are getting posX and posY. and what css properties you set on class tooltip.

Comment: So just check if posX plus the width of the tooltip div are greater than the available viewport width, show the tooltip to the left of the mouse position i.e. reduce the tooltip div width from posX.

Comment: I'm getting the positions through the click event!